# How to send https request in Go or Beego

Tags: go, https, beego

if it is just HTTP request to be sent in go then I will use

```
out, err := json.Marshal(ios_push)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", l_url, bytes.NewBuffer(out))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    fmt.Println("request message is", req)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
```

import will be

```
import "net/http"
```

when I have to send https request from go to a server which accepts data in encoded using a private key. Now how to send an https request by encoding the request data using a private key in go

Comment: Could you please be clear on what you need? Do you mean you need to send binary data or is it just that you need to request `https` ?

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai, i need to send binary data to as above to https

Comment: For sending binary data you will be using the same syntx only difference  is the `Content-Type` and `Marshalling` part.  You need to use "crypo" package to encrypt using public key

Comment: but then where to use key provided for UTF8Encoding so that same key key will used to decode this

Comment: you're mixing up a few things: https with tls is built in, just use https in the url (assuming server has a valid cert) and you get tls while in transit; encryption, see https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta for a good example; UTF8 (a text encoding) is used by Go by default and not a problem here.

Comment: Please clarify the situation. Is it that you need to encrypt your data using `your` `private key` and want the server to read it using your `public key'? If this is the case either server should know your public key already or it will have a way to send the public key once. For these, you  don't need to do anything from go's part

Comment: ohhh,,,,got the point then no need to do extra things for https except data encryption